# No puedo correr nada en Python

Tags: python-3.x, vscode

estoy empezando a aprender programacion. Estoy empezando con python. Me instale VScode hace un par de dias y estuve practicando codigo simple pero de un dia para el otro.. codigo que funcionaba horas atras dejaron de funcionar. "Syntax error" hice de todo. Al comienzo pense que habia un error en el syntax como dice el error pero luego borre todas las lineas y probe codigos simples como print ('Hello World') o a = 1 b = 2
c = a + b -> print(c) pero siempre salia el mismo error entonces me di cuenta que algo raro estaba pasando. Cree nuevos files y lo mismo pero al correr la funcion de Debug todo bien. Entonces probe volver a instalar python 3 en mi mac y como arte de magia todo volvio a funcionar correctamente pero horas despues volvio todo como antes.. necesito ayuda :( [image: foto de un simple print que no funciona]

Comment: Sube una captura del terminal completo.

Comment: Es porque tienes abierto el intérprete de python. Coloca `exit()` para volver a tu consola y ahora si ejecuta el comando

Comment: Es probable que algo en tu computador este interfiriendo o bloqueando a Python, revisa si en tu dispositivo el antivirus no lo anda bloqueando